# Seagate external hard drive is not able to mount either into ubuntu or wondows.showing Dbus Error orh.gtk

Tags: ubuntu, windows-8, hard-drive, external-hard-drive, mount

I have Seagate External Hard dusk and backup plus drive 1TB. I used to use in UBUNTU laptop and windows in VM.It was working fine.But suddenly got mount error. Please find the below exact error:

Unable to mount Seagate Backup Plus Drive-
"DBus error org.gtk.Private.RemoteVolumeMonitor.Failed: An operation is already pending"

and also sametime one more error is coming,plz see in below:

**Unable to mount Seagate Backup Plus Drive:-
Error mounting: mount exited with exit code 13: ntfs_attr_pread_i: ntfs_pread failed: Input/output error
Failed to calculate free MFT records: Input/output error
NTFS is either inconsistent, or there is a hardware fault, or it's a
SoftRAID/FakeRAID hardware. In the first case run chkdsk /f on Windows
then reboot into Windows twice. The usage of the /f parameter is very
important! If the device is a SoftRAID/FakeRAID then first activate
it and mount a different device under the /dev/mapper/ directory, (e.g.
/dev/mapper/nvidia_eahaabcc1). Please see the 'dmraid' documentation
for more details.**

Could anyone plz suggest how it can be resolved and be able to mount my hard disk and back up all the data and use.

Answer (score 0):

Since NTFS is Microsoft property then you need to use chkdsk on Windows to repair any fs errors, be advised that to connect your hdd on a Windows machine and run chkdsk /f on it. Any way even if the fs was destroyed you could extract the data with data recovery tools.

Comment: Thanks for your ans.But could bit elaborate the ans,so i can able to do that as i am new to this hardware trouble shooting. also where shall I find data recovery tools..could you suggest.

Comment: Find a physical Windows 7 or later box, press the power button, wait for Windows till it get fully loaded, find a good usb port and connect your hdd, just connect it don't do any thing, your hdd's led going to blink for several minutes, just wait till that phase get finished, later on your hdd will show up, and now you got a mount point , eg. drive E: or F: whatever, open cmd, type chkdsk /f /x F: notice that to change the drive letter according to your hdd. answer yes for any question, till that finish, safely remove your hdd, try to connect once more just to be sure it would work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You might try mounting your drive on a Apple Mac computer, I have had success with mounting drives that had an identical error. Also, avoid editing or writing files to NTFS drives from linux or anywhere else besides Windows, it can cause problems.